# How to do conditional compare in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have following dataframe in pandas

```
code     prod_a      prod_b     flag
123      MS          MS         to be checked
123      HS          MS         more than 1 prod
123      MS          HS         to be checked
123      HS          MS         more than 1 prod
123      MS          MS         to be checked
```

I want to compare prod_a and prod_b only where `flag = to be checked` and other flag `more than 1 prod` remains as it is. My desired dataframe is as follows

```
code     prod_a      prod_b     flag               final_flag
123      MS          MS         to be checked      matched
123      HS          MS         more than 1 prod   more than 1 prod   
123      MS          HS         to be checked      not matched
123      HS          MS         more than 1 prod   more than 1 prod
123      MS          MS         to be checked      matched
```

How can I do this in pandas.

---

Recreation of dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

data = '''\
code,prod_a,prod_b,flag
123,MS,MS,to be checked
123,HS,MS,more than 1 prod
123,MS,HS,to be checked
123,HS,MS,more than 1 prod
123,MS,MS,to be checked
'''

fileobj = pd.compat.StringIO(data)
df = pd.read_csv(fileobj, sep=',')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) with chain conditions by `&` for bitwise `AND` and inverting by `~`:

```
m1 = df['flag'].eq('to be checked')
m2 = df.prod_a.eq(df.prod_b)

df['final_flag'] = np.select([m1 & m2, m1 & ~m2],['matched','not matched'],default=df['flag'])
print (df)
   code prod_a prod_b              flag        final_flag
0   123     MS     MS     to be checked           matched
1   123     HS     MS  more than 1 prod  more than 1 prod
2   123     MS     HS     to be checked       not matched
3   123     HS     MS  more than 1 prod  more than 1 prod
4   123     MS     MS     to be checked           matched
```

Solution for @Anton vBR:

```
m1 = df['flag'].eq('to be checked')
m2 = df.prod_a.eq(df.prod_b)

df['final_flag'] = df['flag']
df.loc[m1 & m2, 'final_flag'] = 'matched'
df.loc[m1 & ~m2, 'final_flag'] = 'not matched'
print (df)
   code prod_a prod_b              flag        final_flag
0   123     MS     MS     to be checked           matched
1   123     HS     MS  more than 1 prod  more than 1 prod
2   123     MS     HS     to be checked       not matched
3   123     HS     MS  more than 1 prod  more than 1 prod
4   123     MS     MS     to be checked           matched
```

Comment: @AntonvBR - Hmmm, added solution. Maybe if not assign or last fillna it should be nicere :)

Answer (score 0):

try with :

```
df['final_flag'] = df.apply(lambda x : 'matched' if x['flag'] == 'to be checked' and x['prod_a'] == x['prod_b'] else 'not matched')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def udf(row):
    if row.flag == 'to be checked':
        if row.prod_a == row.prod_b:
            return "matched"
        else:
            return "not matched"
    else:
        return row.flag

df['final_flag'] = df.apply(lambda row: udf(row), axis = 1)
```

This should work